# Chapters in TOC horizontally align

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, titletoc

I want to reproduce this TOC style with Latex,

[image]

but I do not know how to do this with titletoc, all my attempts to put the chapter format in line just led me to errors, so, I do not have any kind of MWE...

In resume:

The layout is:

```
PAGE NUMBER

CHAPTER NUMBER
CHAPTER TITLE
```

And put all this in line, like a table.

**EDIT:**

MWE  (??)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\chapter{five}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should at least provide a mwe that provides that many section titles so that people can test answers without having to type a document from scratch.

Comment: Sorry @DavidCarlisle , I put one, but as I said, it is ridiculous...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
\noindent\parbox[t]{.3333\linewidth}{\centering
{\Huge\bfseries #2\par}%
\smallskip
\def\numberline##1{%
\large ##1\par
\normalsize
\par}
#1\par
\bigskip}\hfill}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{one}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\chapter{five}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had a problem with the alignment of these columns, I asked other question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461764/align-a-multicolumn-toc