# Change TOC number system

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, page-numbering, titletoc

In using this [TOC Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461626/chapters-in-toc-horizontally-align/461634#461634), I want to change the number system of the TOC, i.e., I do not want to use the Arabic numbers, but the ancient Greek number system for pages and chapters.

I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{{\greekfonttwo\atticnum{\value{page}}}}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{{\greekfonttwo\atticnum{\value{chapter}}}}
```

But all these led me to get 0 for all chapters and pages numbers in `.toc` file.

I tried to see the definition of the `\chapter` but without success...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xgreek} % package for \atticnum command
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}
\newfontfamily\greekfonttwo[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Quivira} % font to display attic numbers

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \if@mainmatter
\refstepcounter{chapter}%
 \typeout{\@chapapp\space{\greekfonttwo\atticnum{\value{chapter}}}}%
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
 {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
 \else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
\fi
 \else
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
 \fi
 \chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\if@twocolumn
\@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
\else
\@makechapterhead{#2}%
 \@afterheading
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\chapter{one two}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\chapter{five}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the xgreek package, it is rather old. But you can copy the definitions of your numbering system:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}
\newfontfamily\greekfonttwo[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Quivira} %
\makeatletter
\newcount\@attic@num
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\@@atticnum}[1]{%
        \@attic@num#1\relax
        \ifnum\@attic@num<\@ne%
          \space%
          \PackageWarning{xgreek}{%
          Illegal value (\the\@attic@num) for acrophonic Attic numeral}%
        \else\ifnum\@attic@num>249999%
          \space%
          \PackageWarning{xgreek}{%
          Value too large (\the\@attic@num) for acrophonic Attic numeral}%
        \else
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>49999\do{%
               ^^^^^^010147\advance\@attic@num-50000}%
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>9999\do{%
               M\advance\@attic@num-\@M}%
            \ifnum\@attic@num>4999%
               ^^^^^^010146\advance\@attic@num-5000%
            \fi\relax
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>999\do{%
               Χ\advance\@attic@num-\@m}%
            \ifnum\@attic@num>499%
               ^^^^^^010145\advance\@attic@num-500%
            \fi\relax
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>99\do{%
               Η\advance\@attic@num-100}%
            \ifnum\@attic@num>49%
               ^^^^^^010144\advance\@attic@num-50%
            \fi\relax
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>9\do{%
               Δ\advance\@attic@num by-10}%
            \@whilenum\@attic@num>4\do{%
               Π\advance\@attic@num-5}%
            \ifcase\@attic@num\or Ι\or ΙΙ\or ΙΙΙ\or ΙΙΙΙ\fi%
   \fi\fi}
\def\@atticnum#1{%
     \expandafter\@@atticnum\expandafter{\the#1}}
\def\atticnum#1{%
     \@attic@num#1\relax
     \@atticnum{\@attic@num}}
 \makeatother
\renewcommand {\thepage}{{\greekfonttwo \protect\atticnum{\number\value{page}}}}
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{{\greekfonttwo \protect\atticnum{\number\value{chapter}}}}
\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\chapter{one two}
\chapter{two}
\chapter{three}
\chapter{four}
\chapter{five}
\chapter{six}
\chapter{seven}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really thanks!!!! But, what was the specific change that you made from the original definition in `xgreek` package?

Comment: nothing, (apart from using \protect in the \thepage definition).